# Compute using Complex Analysis: integral

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

I am studying a practice midterm and do not know what I need to do to solve this problem?

Compute using Complex Analysis:

$$\int\limits_{|x|=2}\frac{x}{\cos (x)}\mathrm{dx}$$

I tried using a power series to solve, but that did not get me anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** You have two poles inside the contour, namely $x=\pi/2,-\pi/2$.

$$ \int\limits_{|x|=2}\frac{x}{\cos(x)}\mathrm{dx}. $$

**Added:** Here is how you compute the residue at $x=\pi/2$. Since $x=\pi/2$ is a simple pole, then we have

$$ r = \lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} (x-{\pi}/{2})\frac{x}{\cos(x)}=\lim_{x\to \pi/2}\frac{x}{\frac{\cos(x)-0}{x-\pi/2}}=\frac{\pi/2}{-1}= -\pi/2.  $$

Now, you can finish the problem.

Comment: So I integrate from π/2 to −π/2?

Comment: @Tom: You need to use residue theorem or Cauchy formula. You compute the residue at each point then you add them.

Comment: for x=-pi/2 would the answer be:
x/cos(x)*x+(pi/2)= pi/2  as x goes to -pi/2
Therefore adding these equals zero